# Does a PHP to MySQL connection need to be local?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Okay, I know this may be a very noobish question, so forgive me, but right now I have XAMPP and I'm running a local Apache server on my personal computer to test PHP code. I have setup a test database through phpmyadmin on a webhost (Hostgator), but it's looking like if I want to connect to that database I need to have the PHP file that I am editing on the same server because any of the tutorials I read tell me to use locoalhost for the servername requirement when using MySQLi or PDO.

Is this because you 'can't' connect to a database on a separate server? Or because it's just not common because there is a better way to do things? (I've seen hints on being able to download MySQL and phpmyadmin onto my PC, and then importing and exporting tables, but what I've seen hasn't been clear on if that's what I need to do for this or not.)
Thank you!

Comment: You can connect to remote server. Just remote server has to be set to allow remote connections. Most of the free hosts don't allow it.

Comment: the remote server has to allow tcp connections, you have to have an account on that server that allows remote logins e.g. `user@host_you_connect_from`, plus firewalls have to allow the traffic, etc... but in general, no reason you CAN'T use a remote mysql.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's very common practice to use different machines for web and mysql.  There could be a few issues (not familiar with Hostgator but I've dealt with similiar). One is likely firewall. Anything external to the Hostgator network will not have access.

> if I want to connect to that database I need to have the PHP file that
>   I am editing on the same server because any of the tutorials I read
>   tell me to use locoalhost for the servername requirement when using
>   MySQLi or PDO.

I'd find better tutorials. It's good practice to separate your MySQL Server away from your web server.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect to a database server running on another machine provided that the server machine has the appropriate ports open in its firewall and that there is a route between both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I had to go into the Remote MySQL and allow the IP address. Again, maybe a noobish thing, but I had no idea that was something you needed to do. Learned from this though! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, and I see that you figured it out.

However exposing your database to the public internet is never a good idea, so for security purposes it is turned off by default.

If the reason is just for testing your code then it is better to setup your development environment with a local mysql server, this way you don't mess with production database.